# Migrate Azure database server/database different region

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Is there any way to migrate Azure SQL server/database from one geographical region to another region? Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried and the issues you're running into.

Comment: @Gaurav, I have Azure SQL server at North Central US and I want to migrate that my nearest region Southeast Asia.

Comment: I'll ask the question again: What have you tried and the issues you're running into :). Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Not trying but want to know if there is any option for it to migrate, Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Geo-replication to create a replica of your actual databases on the new desired region, then you can failover all of them making databases on the new region the primary databases, now you can drop all secondary databases on the old original region. You can learn about setting up Geo-replication using Azure portal [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-portal).

Another option is to copy the databases to a server located on the desired region using the Copy Database feature as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy).

A third option is exporting the database to a blob storage as bacpac then import it to a SQL Azure server on the new region as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export).

Finally, you can also use SQL Data Sync (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync)) to copy databases to the new region on a new server, and keep the servers synchronized, then you can remove databases from the sync groups, remove SQL Data Sync and drop the original databases.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The official Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/move-resources-across-regions) about moving SQL resources across regions.